# Решите задачу написав при этом соответствующую программу

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Найти количество двузначных чисел, которые не меняют свою сумму цифр при умножении числа на однозначное число n (n = 0 ... 9).
входные данные
Целое число n (0 ≤ n ≤ 9).
Исходные данные
Вывести искомое количество двузначных чисел.
Желательно на С++
Я написал такой код но он не работает(когда я его запускаю мне на экран начинает выводиться бесконечное количество нулей)

```
int n,sum1,sum2,x;
    cin >> n;
    sum1 = 10;
    sum2 = 10;
    
        while(sum1<100)
        {
            sum1++;
            sum2++;
            sum1 = sum1 % 10;
            x = sum1 * n;
            sum2 = sum2 / 10;
            sum1 = sum1 * n;
            sum2 = sum2 * n;
            
            if (sum1 +sum2 ==x)
            
                cout << sum2*10;
            else
            {
                cout << "нема таких чисел";
            }
            
            
        }
```

Comment: Вы забыли последнюю фразу условия - сделать самостоятельно. И прочесть правила ruSO...

Comment: чтобы повысить приоритет, в теме надо писать ключевое слово "быстро" (это на будущее) - например "быстро решите задачу, написав при этом соответствующую программу"

Comment: Что значит не работает? Выдаёт какие-то ошибки или неверные результаты? Укажите это в вопросе

Comment: Также уточните заголовок вопроса. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так годится?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n < 0 || n > 9) {
        cerr << "Wrong input\n";
        return 1;
        }

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 10; i <= 99; ++i) {
        int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, k = i, j = i * n;

        while (k || j) {
            sum1 += k % 10;
            sum2 += j % 10;
            k /= 10;
            j /= 10;
            }

        if (sum1 == sum2) {
            cout << i << " and " << i* n << "\n";
            count++;
            }
        }

    cout << "There are " << count << " that numbers\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        sum1++;
        sum1 = sum1 % 10;
```

вот этот код вам никогда и не даст достигнуть чего-то большего 9 :)

1. зачем вы вообще используете `while`, когда для вашей задачи идеально подходит `for`

   ```
    for (int value = 10; value < 100; value ++)
   ```
2. ваш код как-то вообще не соответствует приведенному вами же условию задачи

в условии сказано - что есть некоторое число с некоторой суммой цифр
сумму цифр двухзначного числа `value` можно подсчитать так:

```
const sum1 = (value % 10) + ((value / 10) % 10);
```

а сумму произведения двухзначного числа `value` на `n` абсолютно также, только учитывая, что число все таки может быть трехзначным

```
const value2 = value * n;
const sum2 = (value2 % 10) + ((value2 / 10) % 10) + ((value2 / 100) % 10);
```

3. в добавок в задаче требуется подсчитать кол-во таких чисел, а не сами числа:

   ```
   int count = 0;
   ...
   if (sum1 == sum2)
       count ++;
   ```

Comment: Большая спасибо, я впервые на stackoverflow и не ожидал, что так быстро и качественно получу ответ. И как уже все заметили я начинающий и делаю много ошибок поэтому извините если чем-то разозлил)